# videos file can not uploading to s3 by using PHP s3 class

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

hey everyone again i have lettle problem when i upload video file to s3 AWS

it get warning message : 

`PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in F:\xampp\htdocs\test\S3.php on line 2341, referer: https://127.0.0.1/test/upload.php`
the video size is (20 Mo) max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
ini_set('max_execution_time',500); // 500 Seconds
```

above code for limiting execution time.

Comment: tnx so mutch brother

Comment: what about the security when i changed set_time_limit value from default value 30s To xxx s value

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP is configured with a max execution time of 30s

you can change it with [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.set-time-limit.php)

Comment: what about the security when i changed set_time_limit value from default value 30s To xxx s value